# nodejs: how to print more error information in close listener?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have the following code that handles http request.

```
request.connection.addListener('close', function(had_error) {
   console.log(had_error);
   ...
```

I want to print more information of error, but it only prints "true".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **Error event** to trace the error. It returns the Error object with full details.

```
request.connection.addListener('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error.reason|| error.message);
});
```

Since connection has been *deprecated* from v15,if you are using latest version, use this also

```
request.on('error',function(error){
    console.log(error.reason|| error.message);
});
```

Comment: It works, although I use "console.log(error)" as I got undefined for error.reason.

Comment: try error.message instead